# Calculate betweenness-centrality and show percentage

Tags: neo4j, cypher, percentage, network-analysis

I´m doing some Analytics on my Neo4j graph and know I´m getting stucked with another problem. 
My working query is the following:

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((source:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(target:Person)) 
WHERE id(source) < id(target) and length(p) > 1 
UNWIND nodes(p)[1..-1] AS n 
RETURN n.id AS id, n.firstname AS firstname, n.lastname AS lastname, count(*) as betweenness 
ORDER BY betweenness DESC
```

this works as expected and gives me a list like this:

[image: result betweenness]

So far, so good. But now I would like to have an additional column where the percental value based on all shortest paths is shown up. 
I´ve tried to simply add `100.0 * SUM(betweenness) / count(p) AS percent` but this results in an error **Variable `betweenness` not defined (line 4, column 119 (offset: 267))**

If somebody knows how to handle this, please tell me ;)

thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use [WITH](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/):

- Pass `p` and other properties for the next context using [WITH](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/).
- With `betweenness` calculate `percent` and return all.

Try it:

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((source:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(target:Person)) 
WHERE id(source) < id(target) and length(p) > 1 
UNWIND nodes(p)[1..-1] AS n 
WITH p, n.id AS id, n.firstname AS firstname, n.lastname AS lastname, count(*) as betweenness
RETURN id, firstname, lastname, betweenness, 100.0 * SUM(betweenness) / count(p) AS percent
ORDER BY betweenness DESC
```

Comment: ok.. i´ve tested this query but then my betweenness-factor is '1' for all nodes and the percentage-factor is '100'

Comment: hmmm... Try: `MATCH p=allShortestPaths((source:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(target:Person)) 
WHERE id(source) < id(target) and length(p) > 1 
UNWIND nodes(p)[1..-1] AS n 
WITH count(p) as countP, n.id AS id, n.firstname AS firstname, n.lastname AS lastname, count(*) as betweenness
RETURN id, firstname, lastname, betweenness, 100.0 * SUM(betweenness) / countP AS percent
ORDER BY betweenness DESC` If it works I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi @Andy Did my answer help you solve your problem? If so, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.